# Spring is not able to autowire a dependency

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have an application which is not a dynamic web project. I have the arrangement such that its like a library in form of a jar which is exposed via interfaces. I am trying to auto wire this interface into my API project which is Dynamic web project. But it throws bean creation exception

1. I have a MyLibraryCofiguration class in library which has @Configuration and  @Import alongwith @ComponentScan.

```
@Configuration
@Import({ BasicConfiguration.class, OperationalLoggingConfiguration.class, RestConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan("nl.ming.cram")
public class MyConfiguration() {

    public MyConfiguration() {
        packages("nl.ming.cram.gateway");
    }

    @Bean
    public MyInterface getMyInterface() {
        return new MyImpl();
    }
}
```

2. My API project has MyApiCofiguration class which has @Import in which I am importing my MyLibraryCofiguration class. In the same class I have used:

```
    @Configuration
    @Import({
            MyConfiguration.class
    })
    @ComponentScan({"nl.ming.api.creditcardlist"})
    public class CreditCardListConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
         public MyInterface getMyInterface() {
            return new CramImpl();
       }
    }
```

3. In my API project , in MyApiService class  - I have @Autowired MyInterface to access methods of library jar as shown below:

```
    @Component
    public class MyAPIService {
   
        @Autowired
        MyInterface MyInterface;    
    }
```

It throws a Bean creation exception for getMyInterface as is shown below -

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'creditCardService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:
> `nl.ing.cram.gateway.CramInterfacenl.ing.api.creditcardlist.services.CreditCardService.cramIface;`
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getCramInterface': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nl.ing.cram.dao.CramDaonl.ing.cram.gateway.CramImpl.cramDao;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cramDao': Injection of resource dependencies failed;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [nl.ing.sc.customerrequest.createcustomerrequest1.CreateCustomerRequestServiceOperationClient] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, lookup=, authenticationType=CONTAINER)}

Comment: You said you are autowiring (@Autowired) the interface in your service. How is the service accessed and where? Can you post the source code for the classes?

Comment: If you autowire the interface in the service and the service is not also a bean or something then thie error will happen.

Comment: @AlexandruGodri - Code attached :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No spring can be used in any kind of Java application.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
```

I am able to see above exception, this means spring is able to find the type which your injecting but not its implementation.

Check in your spring-config :-

```
<context:component-scan base-package="..." />
```

Cause of exception in your exception stack trace :-
In your nl.ing.cram.gateway.CramImpl.cramDao class it failed to inject the dependency of type CreateCustomerRequestServiceOperationClient because it couldn't able to find its implementation.

Comment: Any way are you  able to sight the issue in my code which is causing this exception?

Comment: Did you enable the component scanning in spring-config.xml ?

Comment: CreateCustomerRequestServiceOperationClient do you have implementation of this class ? Check my edit.

Comment: Its a Interface and yes implementation is there but I am pretty sure , it has nothing to do with this class. Once i remove the MyInterface code, the api does a maven clean install again.

Comment: No qualifying bean of type [nl.ing.sc.customerrequest.createcu
stomerrequest1.CreateCustomerRequestServiceOperationClient]...See the exception stack trace.

Comment: Change the subject of question or accept my edit. Current subject may attract downvotes.